# Try appending items to a default dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

I have a function:

```
#Should be named tryAppendingToListInADict but I'm too lazy for that long of a name
def tryAppendingToDict(dictionary, key, item):
    try:
        #append to an existing list
        dictionary[key].append(item)
    except KeyError:
        #list doesn't exist yet, so make one
        dictionary[key] = [item]
```

In most cases I use this function on one dictionary, let's call it `defaultDictOfLists`, as in my code looks like

```
tryAppendingToDict(defaultDictOfLists, 'spam', 'eggs')
tryAppendingToDict(defaultDictOfLists, 'spam', 'beacon')
tryAppendingToDict(defaultDictOfLists, 'not spam', 'yuck!')
#...
tryAppendingToDict(differentDict, 'spam', 'I don't like spam!')
```

So I wanted to try and make a keyword argument to my function that would assume you're appending items to the `defaultDictOfLists`. However, the main problem here, is that this function is imported from a separate module (and should remain there), so a simple

```
def tryAppendingToDict(key, item, dictionary = defaultDictOfLists):
```

raises a `NameError`, and `globals()['defaultDictOfLists']` raises a `KeyError`.

Is there a way to fix it? It would clarify my code a lot and speed up the coding process as well.

---

**Edit**

I'm not using `defaultdict(list)` because this dictionary is passed to a Django template and those don't handle defaultdicts very well for some reason. So I'd have to convert this defaultdict back to a regular dict, which takes O(n) time, if I recall correctly.

Comment: You keep using the term "defaultDict" but it seems as if you're trying to implement a feature that looks just like The [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).  If you're using 2.5 or later you can just use that one.

Comment: i would add a setter function for the value of defaultDictOfLists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just *monkeypatch* it? You can:

```
from module import tryAppendingToDict as _tryAppendingToDict

def tryAppendingToDict(key, item, dictionary=defaultDictOfLists):
    return _tryAppendingToDict(dictionary, key, item)
```

And use this function in the module where `defaultDictOfLists` is actually defined.

Moreover, I can't see the usefulness of this code, sure you can use `defaultdict`, but you can also use dictionaries' [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=try%20except%20block#dict.setdefault) method. It will reduce your dictionary insertions to one line, turning `tryAppendingToDict()` useless:

```
>>>d={}
>>>d.setdefault('key',['value'])
>>>d
{'key': ['value']}
```

Comment: Yes, monkey patching is a good idea. `setdefault` not really, since I have to try appending items, not adding them.

Comment: @Dunno You can do this with `setdefault`: `d.setdefault('key',['value']).append('value2')` and you'll get `{'key':['value','value2']}`. It's quite powerful. `setdefault` returns the `default` value when called, so you can apply methods on it.

Comment: Yes but I can't do it in a for loop, because `d.setdefault(key,[value]).append(value)` will append `value` twice. I'd have to use `if` or `try` anyway.

Comment: I'm not trying to sell you `setdefault` :) but you can do: `d.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)`. Default empty list, and append `value` to it. I'm quite fond of that function when working with dicts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have group items in lists that are values of dictionary, you can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections

data = collections.defaultdict(list)
raw = [(i % 3, i) for i in range(10)] # sample data

for key, value in raw:
    data[key].append(value)
```

Without much trouble you get what you want:

```
In [10]: data
Out[10]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: [0, 3, 6, 9], 1: [1, 4, 7], 2: [2, 5, 8]})
```

see http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict for more information and use cases.

Comment: See my edited question, sorry for not clarifying this earlier